# Footer issue in Magento Shopping cart page

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, php

The footer in my Magento shopping cart page is misaligned. The footer for all the other pages are okay.

The shopping cart takes the one-column template. Other pages that use the one-column template are displaying properly.

Help me fix it.

Comment: this is a css issue most likely, to help you out you should present your store so we could actually see the DOM and CSS used

Comment: It is here http://parisera.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution is to change `.footer-container` (line 1700) to:

```
.footer-container {
    border-top:0px solid #b6d1e2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1003px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the footer div is outside the "page" div, in your 404, for example.
Anyway, removing float: left; of div id=footer_down_main solves your problem